# Python & Django web app - auto emails not sending

Tags: python, django, email

I had a web app developed but found the automated emails are not sending.
I found the .py file for sending the email, but cannot find another file calling this.
[filetree showing .py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjUew.png)

Is there a standard file to place a call to the send_due_email.py file?

If I find that there is nothing calling this file to run, where should the code be placed?

I want the emails sent once a week - maybe every sunday
How can I setup the software to run this file every Sunday?

***Edit
Cron works well for this. I have it working thank you. For testing I added the following line to send an email every minute

- - - - - /root/venv/bin/python3 /root/manage.py send_due_email

Comment: Looks like a custom management command, it can be called using `python manage.py send_due_email` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: I can run the file using '''python manage.py send_due_email''' but where would I put a call to run it on a schedule? In manage.py?

Comment: There are many solutions for running jobs/commands on a schedule, it's not easy to say which is the right choice for you. Try looking at celerybeat or cron for example